# How do I fix Helium backup/restore over Google Drive?

Tags: backup, clockworkmod-recovery, restore, backup-manager, helium

I am trying to back up all my game saves to Google Drive using Helium. I can backup a few game saves, but eventually I receive this error:

```
Backup Error
An error occurred while performing your app backup. A log of the error has been sent to ClockworkMod.

Click Backup to attempt to backup the remaining apps.
```

To fix this, I either clear the cache of Helium on my old phone or reinstall it, which seems to fix it.

If I try to list all the backups I have in Google Drive on my new phone, I occasionally get:

```
An error has occurred while retrieving your app list.
```

Once again, I need to clear the cache or reinstall to fix this.

When I can actually try to restore, many apps get stuck on a set percentage such as 93%, and then gives me the same message as above except "Restore Failed".